# Find the numerator of 6/8

Tags: evaluation

The statement Numerator[6/8] evaluates to 3.
Numerator[Hold[6/8] does not work.
What function NewNumerator[6/8] evaluates to 6?

Comment: `Numerator[Unevaluated[6/8]]`

Comment: Why not use `Extract[]` on the held fraction?

Comment: `num[frac_] := frac[[1, 1]]`
`den[frac_] := 1/frac[[1, 2]]`
`num@HoldForm[6/8]`
`den@HoldForm[6/8]`